# Does "Update Profile" extend "View Profile"?

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm developing a web application and I'm on the design stage. In the use cases, users can view their profile on a certain page, and they can also update their profile information from that page. Now I wonder if the **Update Profile** operation extend the **View Profile** operation in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply speaking: do not use extend or include with use cases. A single use case bubble represents a unique added value the system under consideration returns to the actor. If you can not tell that something is added value, it is not an use case. Include/extend are in most cases used as functional decomposition. But use cases are synthesized, which is the exact opposite.

In your case (and where it comes to CRUD) think of what is behind the scenes. Here it is dealing with a profile. So you could call it Maintain Profile which includes (in internal steps) the viewing and editing. Usually you can simply constrain functional parts. Furthermore your system description will be more lucid when using less bubbles. Remember: if your use cases start looking like spider webs, your system design is most likely wrong.

Comment: I basically agree with your point that it's better to hide details in use cases, but I'm confused at that use cases that's too general may also make the new added value invisible. For example, there is a PDF Reader software that only supports users reading PDF on it, and the use cases related to this could be "Maintain PDF documents" like you said. But now the developers want to improve that software and add a new functionality of editing PDF, so if that use case is unmodified, the new added value could not be put in the use cases which should include it .

Comment: @IT_Layman Use all answers with a grain of salt. A PDF viewer has probably two use cases: View and Edit Document. And yes, I'd regard both as independent. Why here? Well, the border as to where to prefer the one or other approach is indifferent. My answer goes for the most CRUD cases. There are quite some to be looked at differently.